# gmapping-get-empty-map-coordinates

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I wonder whether is possible to get the coordinates of empty space of the global map. The thing is that, I would like to move the robot to a random goal that is within the empty space of the map, so the navigation stack can plan the path and use actionlib to move the robot.

In advance thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65569/gmapping-get-empty-map-coordinates/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-06-20**:
Please separate your tags using space, not minus. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can subscribe to a map [topic](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) from your node and find randomly indices of some free space. Then you can convert these indices to Cartesian  coordinates (using map metadata).

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-20**:
hi, nice to hear that, Thanx :)